# What is the damage increase of Symmetra's Photon Projector?

Tags: overwatch

I was wondering if anyone knew what the damage increase of her primary weapon (photon projector's energy beam) was, per second.

Comment: I dont thing there's Damage boost, only max-range boost of 2m

Comment: The longer that the energy beam is locked on a target, the higher the damage output gets. My question is the numbers for that damage output (over-time)

Comment: As I said, I'm pretty sure those haven't changed from 7.5/15/30 per hit (4 hits per second) takes a second to move to higher damage tier.

Comment: I know that the damage output hasn't changed, I just wanted to know the damage changes per second, which you just answered. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Symetra Photon projector does
7.5/15/30 dmg per hit. She does 4 his per second and it takes a second to move up a tire.

Meaning she'll do 120 dps after 3 seconds of continuous shooting at someone.

It's worth nothing that this damage output will not be changed in the reworked Symetra. The only change regarding her weapon is the range. It's being boosted to 7m from 5m.

Comment: The damage only ramps up while dealing damage, and decays at the same rate after 1 second of not dealing any damage.